# Eclipse Docking Windows implementation: does Eclipse reimplement Docking Windows on top of Graphic Context instead of using native ones?

Tags: java, eclipse, gtk, swt, docking

I'm trying to implement docking windows in my application on GTK+ and decided to mimic to their implementation in SWT over GTK+. I'm interested in moving docking subwindows and creating and moving tabs between notebooks/TabFolders within dock windows. Here's a dock window example (shown with red frame):

[image]

I've looked into CTabFolder and CTabItem classes family and found implementation of notebook  functionality in them. Alas, it is carried out from scratch on top of basic 2D rendering capabilities of GC (graphics context) class on top of native (GTK+Cairo/Win32/Cocoa) graphics primitives.

But this is true only for [close/restore/maximize/minimize](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20Custom%20Widgets/common/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CTabFolder2Adapter.java#n41) capabilities of CTabs. I've failed to find drag subwindow/dock subwindow/resize subwindow capabilities implementation. Could you point me to them?

SWT source online: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20Custom%20Widgets/common/org/eclipse/swt/custom

Thanks in advance.